# How to handle long session data in PHP?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am developing a MCQ website, where I am generating a question set which is not limited by any fixed number. Currently there are 20000 question in my database. So if user selects all subject and topic the question set will contain all those rows are in database.

I am using an array in session data to store them. Also the system repeats the question after a fixed number of time if users fails to answer them.

The system is developed for below 15 years students. Now, when I am accessing the site alone, there are no issues. But, when all pupils say, 100 are using the site the system gets very slow.

I believe there are no other valid reason without the session variable. Can you guide me how can I sort out the issue?

Comment: I have a similiar question for you _"How long is a piece of string"_ If you can answer mine without any details then possibly someone here can answer yours! Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, I am storing question ids(shuffled and rearranged as per need) in the session variable along with the other data. So say, I have choose all available subject and topics then set will be generated from all the available questions in the database. As it's a system for self study, there are no time limit. So user an answer as much as question they want. As I told, it's working ok when I am testing with 3 pcs, but getting slow down when I am testing with 100 or more systems. So, I assume it's due to the high memory access and ram usage. So, if you could give me a suggestion it would be great.